# remove "Template path hints in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

please vist "http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/"

I set "Template Path Hints = yes" and " Add Block Names to Hints to "yes"  in "Default wide" store.

after that I set to no .

But still, template paths are displaying in top left and bottom footer.

How to remove those "paths".

I cleared cache.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check ur store view settings and refresh cache from cache management.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I checked store view . I set template path hints and add block names to yes. I refreshed cache.

Comment: so it worked!!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through each of the store views/websites and make sure it's disabled. You can do this from the drop down on the top left of the System > Configuration panel

[image: How to change the store]

Once you've checked all those settings flush the cache just to be certain.

Comment: @user3483987 no problem, could you mark this as the solution please?

Comment: yes, i did it....